# UWP ListBox is not responding to changes in the HorizontalAlignment

Tags: xaml, uwp, listbox, grid

In the XAML below:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Button1"></Button>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Why does the ListBox occupy the entire width, even when the HorizontalAlignment is set to Center?

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided by you, you haven’t set the `Width` property of `ListBox`. The default value of `Width` is `Double.NaN`. If the parent element’s `Width` is set, then the width of the `ListBox` will stretch to available width of its parent element. If the parent element’s `Width` is `auto`, then the `Listbox` will just take up required space.

In your scenario, you divided the height of the `Grid` into two equal parts by two `ColumnDefinition` tags. Therefore, your ListBox’s width will be equal to the cell’s width in the `Row 1` and `Column 0`. You could try to set the value of `Width` property as `auto` of the first `ColumnDefinition` to view that the `ListBox` will only occupy the required width.

If you want center the `ListBox` in its parent element, you could set the `Width` of `ListBox`. Then the `ListBox` will be in the center of the cell.

For example:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200">
```

If you want the items of `ListBox` in the center, you need to set the `HorizontalAlignment` property of `ListBoxItem`.

For example:

```
<ListBoxItem HorizontalAlignment="Center">Item1</ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem HorizontalAlignment="Center">Item2</ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem HorizontalAlignment="Center">Item3</ListBoxItem>
```

Comment: If your problem is resolved, it is better if you could mark the answer so that poeple with the same problems could find a solution quickly.